# Mocking an async method in React test

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a React component that calls an async method like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  serviceObj.getData().then(response => this.setState({data: response.data}));
  foo(this.state.data);
}
```

The state value `data` is set to a default value at first. How can I assert in a unit test that the method `foo` is called with the new state value after the async method `getData()` returns? I have tried it with a naive test using `react-test-library` like follows, but this does not work; the method is called with the default value, not the mock returned value.

```
it('renders with embedded D3 chart', async () => {
  const serviceObj = jest.mock('serviceModule', () => {
    getData: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({data: "test"})
  });

  render(<MyComponent />);

  expect(foo.mock.calls[0][0]).toStrictEqual("test");
});
```

Comment: Are you using react-testing-library?

Comment: @ReturnOfTheMac Yes, I tagged the question as such. I will make this more explicit in the post.

Comment: With RTL, it's recommended to write integration tests, not unit tests. So basically testing what the user sees. What would the user expect to see in your case when the data loads?

Comment: @ReturnOfTheMac Thanks for the help. In this case, when my component is mounted it fetches some data from a remote source, then calls a method on another object to pass in that data. This other object is in fact a D3 wrapper, so it renders a chart. However, I want to this my main component in isolation; the D3 rendering code is in another object, so I wanted to simply test here that I indeed invoke the D3 wrapper object methods.

Comment: Ah ok. In that case it's not really a React Testing Library question since that library is far more concerned with checking for things that the user sees, like headings, inputs, checkboxes etc. Sounds like more of a "jest" question.

Comment: Can you share the full code for the component under test?